# CMAKE: Build library and link against it

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake (on Linux with GNU make and g++) to build a project with two sub-directories:  MyLib and MyApp.  MyLib contains source for a static library; MyApp needs to link against that library.  I'm trying to build on Linux with generated makefiles using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MyProj)
include_directories (MyLib)
file(GLOB MyLibSrc MyLib/*.cpp)
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${MyLibSrc})
file(GLOB MyAppSrc MyApp/*.cpp)
add_executable(MyApplication ${MyAppSrc})
target_link_libraries(MyApplication MyLibrary)
```

This 'almost' works.  It fails at link time because while it generates libMyLibrary.a - it is in the root.  When I add:

```
link_directories(${MyProj_BINARY_DIR})
```

it makes no difference.

I've got a few (inter-linked) questions:

1. What's the best way to coerce cmake into building my library and executable into a 'staging directory' — say MyStage — to keep targets separate from source?
2. How do I convince cmake to link the application against the library?
3. If I wanted to build a debug and a release version, what's the best way to extend my cmake scripts to do this — making sure that the debug application links against the debug library and the release application against the release library?

I'm a relative newcomer to cmake. I've read what I can find on the web, but find myself struggling to get my library to link with my executable. This sort of a configuration, to my mind, should be quite common. An example from which to crib would be very helpful, but I've not found one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use "out of the source build". Make a directory used only for build and while in it, call

   ```
   cmake <path to the sources, it may be relative>
   ```
2. Either use

   ```
   link_directories(${MyProj_BINARY_DIR}/MyLib)
   ```

   or make CMakeLists.txt in each subdirectory - that would be better for project larger than very small.
3. This is a bit tricky, check out CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE in the docs (you can set it and/or "if" by it). You can also set it from command line:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
   ```

Comment: I can see how (1) could work - though I don't think it's neat.  I don't want CMakeLists.txt in my 'staging directory' alongside my library, if I can help it.

Comment: Uhm, no, no, CMakeLists.txt stay in the source tree. The path that is passed as an argument to cmake is the directory that contains the top-level CMakeLists.txt. In this setup, the "staging" dir is completely empty prior to cmake invocation.

Answer (score 32):

Well, it is better to read this [example](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html) and do exactly as suggested.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MyProj CXX)
add_subdirectory(MyLib)
add_subdirectory(MyApp)
```

Then for each subdirectory specified, CMakeLists.txt files are created

MyLib\CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES *.cpp)
add_library(MyLib ${SRC_FILES})
```

MyApp\CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB SRC_FILES *.cpp)
add_executable(MyApp ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MyApp MyLib)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's the easiest way I've found. But the webpage seems to have been changed, they have a new example now

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered the 'optimal' solution to (1)... so, thought I should post it here:

```
SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY MyStage)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY MyStage)
```

The thing that confused me previously is that static libraries are not considered a LIBRARY by Cmake - they're considered to be ARCHIVEs.

Comment: The only helpful answer I have found! There naming is so confusing!