# CMAKE: Build executable and library and link them

Tags: c++, cmake

I use CMake for building and want to keep my project flexible and consice, so I decided to group code files in separate folders. 
But in `src` folder i have subfolder with code i want separate into library. I made `CMakeLists.txt` where i want code to compile, but CMake throws error.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819647/cmake-build-library-and-link-against-it) question and answers didn't help. 
I think i messed up somewhere else (or solution is a bit dated)

Here is my catalog tree:

```
uint32-sort/
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt           $1 // Main build file, for whole project
├── include                     // Headers folder
│   ├── file_manager.hpp
│   └── sort_container.hpp
└── src                         // Source folder
    ├── main.cpp        
    └── sort_lib                // Lib source folder
    ├── CMakeLists.txt       $2 // Build file for lib
        ├── file_manager.cpp
        └── sort_container.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt $1 :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

SET(PROJECT_NAME "Uint32Sort")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.01 LANGUAGES CXX)


include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
add_executable(uint32sort main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sort_lib/)


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SortCore)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

CMakeLists.txt $2 :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

SET(PROJECT_NAME "SortCore")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 0.01 LANGUAGES CXX)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB SRC_LIB_FILES *.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIB_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} openmp)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

I expected to run `cmake ..` in `uint32-sort/build` folder and get executable linked with library from `uint32-sort/src/sort_lib/` but everything what i get is this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "Uint32Sort" which is not built by
  this project.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says: you have no target named `Uint32Sort`. You have however a target named `uint32sort`:

```
#              v---------- executable target
add_executable(uint32sort main.cpp)
```

So your `target_link_libraries` call should use the target as its first parameter:

```
# use PRIVATE of no public header use SortCore
target_link_libraries(uint32sort PUBLIC SortCore)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Everything worked now (and after i corrected some additional mistakes).

Comment: I would suggest you to look for the target based API of cmake. It really helps organising larger project with external dependencies

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus [here's a documentation link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html)

Comment: By the way, do you know good books about cmake, except documentation? Documentation, is good then you know what you want. But im a beginner here and do not always know what i want. I found [this one](https://riptutorial.com/cmake), but it's 2 years old, and cmake upgraded since 2017...

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus unfortunately, no. I learned it by trying to create the best setup I could and by looking at how high quality library did it. Blog posts such as [It's Time To Do CMake Right](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/) also really helped me.